how to change the status bar colour for react native drawer in iOS
I want to change the colour above the drawer navigator which is white right now to red. Is there any default setting for iOS where all the screen which we navigate will be always on the colour which we set?

import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import GalleryScreen from './Screens/GalleryScreen';
import ImageDetail from './Screens/ImageDetail';
import DetailScreen from './Screens/DetailScreen';
import Navbar from './Screens/Navbar';
import NotificationScreen from './Screens/NotificationScreen';
import NewNotification from './Screens/NewNotification';
import NewGalleryScreen from './Screens/NewGalleryScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './Screens/DetailsScreen';

// Create a Drawer Navigator
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

// Create a Stack Navigator for Login flow
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

// Custom Drawer Content Component
const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => (
  <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/326055/pexels-photo-326055.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1' }}
        style={styles.logo}
      />
      <Text style={styles.name}>John Doe</Text>
      <Text style={styles.email}>ts1_teacher1@yopmail.com</Text>
      <Text style={styles.school}>Test App School 2</Text>
    </View>
    <DrawerItemList {...props} />
  </DrawerContentScrollView>
);

// Drawer Navigator containing main screens
const HomeDrawerNavigator = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator
    initialRouteName="GalleryScreen"
    drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
  >
    <Drawer.Screen name="GalleryScreen" component={GalleryScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Navbar" component={Navbar} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="NotificationScreen" component={NotificationScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="nNotification" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Notification" component={NewNotification} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="NewGalleryScreen" component={NewGalleryScreen} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
);

// Main App Component
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#fff" barStyle="light-content" translucent={true} />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Login"
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#C8102E', // Red color for the header
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff', // White color for the header text
          }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeDrawerNavigator} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="GalleryScreen" component={GalleryScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ImageDetails" component={ImageDetail} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="DetailScreen" component={DetailScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="NewGalleryScreen" component={NewGalleryScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="DetailsScreen"
            component={DetailsScreen}
            options={{
              headerShown: true,
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#C8102E',
              },
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
};

// Styles for Custom Drawer Content
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#C8102E',
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 40,
  },
  logo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  name: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  email: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  school: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  drawerItems: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;


I tried to make the drawer navigator with a static info and colour red for the upper part of the drawer navigator but that white gap I want to change that colour to red

Add padding to the DrawerContentScrollView to fill the space properly and set the background color of the drawer content container.
Add contentContainerStyle to DrawerContentScrollView:
<DrawerContentScrollView {...props}  contentContainerStyle={styles.drawerContainer}/>
Update drawerContainer style:
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  drawerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#C8102E', 
  },
 
});

Update StatusBar background color:
<StatusBar backgroundColor="#C8102E" barStyle="light-content" translucent={true} />

Use drawerStyle to style the drawer component. Something like this:
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    drawerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  }}
  drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
...
</Drawer.Navigator>


I have already used it and its not working

Not in the code you provided.
